# Vue-chartjs not rendering chart until page resize

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using vue-chartjs to create charts for my application. I am passing the `chartData` as a prop. My chart doesn't render at first but does when I resize the window. Here is my code. First the chart component:

```html
<script>
    import { Doughnut, mixins } from "vue-chartjs";
    const { reactiveProp } = mixins;
    export default {
        extends: Doughnut,
        mixins: [reactiveProp],
        mounted() {
            this.render();
        },
        methods: {
            render() {
                console.log(this.chartData)
                let options = {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                };
                this.renderChart(this.chartData, options);
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Now here is the code from the component where the chart is displayed:

template part

```html
<v-container>
    <ProjectDoughnutChart :chart-data="chartData" />
</v-container>
```

script part

```js
components: {
    ProjectDoughnutChart,
},

data() {
    return {
        chartData: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [],
                    data: [],
                },
            ],
        },
    };
},

setChartsTimesheets() {
    this.timesheets.forEach((timesheet) => {
        let typeTotal = 0;
        this.timesheets
            .filter((timesheet1) => timesheet1.type==timesheet.type)
            .forEach((timesheet1) => {
                typeTotal+=timesheet1.billableAmount;
            });
        if (this.chartData.labels.indexOf(timesheet.type) === -1) {
            let colors = this.getTaskColors(timesheet.type);
            this.chartData.labels.push(timesheet.type);
            this.chartData.datasets[0].data.push(typeTotal);
            this.chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(colors.color);
            this.chartData.datasets[0].hoverBackgroundColor.push(colors.hover);
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem using a similar solution as "[Chart with API data](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data)" from the documentation.

TL;DR: Adding a v-if on the chart

Answer (score 0):

For people, that have similar problem, but not using vue.js or the *official* solution doesnt cut it. I had to `chart.update()` the graph to show values, that were added after the graph was created.

See the example. If you comment the `chart.update()` line, the graph will not refresh until the window is resized.

```js
let chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [1, 5, 12, 8, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'green',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true,
    },
    stacked: false,
    responsive: true,
  }
});

// adding data to graph after it was created (like data from API or so...)
chart.data.labels.push("new data");
chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(9);

// with chart.update(), the changes are shown right away
// without chart.update(), you need to resize window first 
chart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```